# Rationally parameterize quadratic surface

Tags: surfaces, rational-functions, parametrization

If I have a multivariate polynomial described by function $f(x,y,z)$ where $f(x,y,z)=a(x)+b(y)+c(z)$, and where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are each univariate polynomials of degree $2$, and $f(x,y,z)=0$ describes a 3-dimensional surface.  Is there a mechanism for finding functions $x(u,v)$, $y(u,v)$, and $z(u,v)$ as rational functions of $u$ and $v$ such that $f(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))=0$?

What I have tried so far to solve this is explained in the paper by Chandrajit L. Bajaj on [Rational Parametrizations of Nonsingular
Real Cubic Surfaces](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cfba/f845f1ec20ec71a01f3c6529b7847f68dcf8.pdf).  My surface is quadratic, but some other papers I have read on the subject which cite this one as a reference have indicated that the method would supposedly work for quadratics as well.   However, every pair of skew lines that I pick from one particular surface I tried this with results in a denominator of $0$ in the rational parameterization formula as computed by its method, and is thus unsuitable.  I would, ideally, prefer a more general system that worked for singular surfaces anyways.